# converting array values to time in php

Tags: php

I have an array which contains time values in **GMT**. :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [h] => 5
            [m] => 0
         )
)
```

Here `Array[0][0]` is the array for start time and `Array[0][1]` is the array for end time.

Now what I am creating time using date time as:

```
    $timezone = new DateTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"); //Converting GMT to IST.

    $startTime = new DateTime();
    $startTime->setTime($Array[1][0]["hour"], $Array[1][0]["minute"]);
    $startTime->setTimezone($timezone);
    $startTime->format('h:i a');   //output 10:30 PM // Should be 10:30 AM

    $endTime = new DateTime();
    $endTime->setTime($Array[1][1]["hour"], $Array[1][1]["minute"]);
    $endTime->setTimezone($timezone);
    $endTime->format('h:i a');    //output 10:30 PM //ok

So My $startTime and $endTime both has the same value of `10:30` PM but I want the startTime to have value of `10:00 AM`because its period was `AM` in the array.
```

Comment: In your code you never access [period] inside the array. So, how is the program supposed to know which it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating new `Datetime` object You have to specify timezone, because default value is taken from PHP configuration and this may not be set to GMT. So initialization of `$startTime` and `$endTime` should be:

```
$startTime = new DateTime('', new DateTimeZone('GMT'));
$endTime = new DateTime('', new DateTimeZone('GMT'));
```

Then when You are using `setTime()` You have to add 12 hours when PM period is taken. It should look like that:

```
$startTime->setTime($Array[1][0]["hour"] + ($Array[1][0]["period"] === 'PM' ? 12 : 0), $Array[1][0]["minute"]);
$endTime->setTime($Array[1][1]["hour"] + ($Array[1][1]["period"] === 'PM' ? 12 : 0), $Array[1][0]["minute"]);
```

Rest of the code looks fine, besides in You example `$Array[1]` is undefined. `$Array[0]` is set.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `DateTime::createFromFormat()`:

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('g:m A', '5:30 PM', new DateTimeZone('GMT'));
$d->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
var_dump($d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

Gives:

```
string(19) "2017-03-16 22:30:00"
```

You can create the string `'5:30 PM'` by combining the elements of your array. Please note that you must add a leading `0` to the minutes if they are less than 10, e.g: 9 minutes -> `09`